# How to pass callback functions to store in @reduxjs/toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am trying to implement an api request/response history in my react application. I am using **Redux Toolkit** for coding redux logic. I would like to have a sequence of requests followed by responses which optionally may have button to call the next request function. All the steps are saved in my redux state as an `apiHistory.entries` array of objects. What I would like to achieve is to pass `callToAction` object to some of the entry objects and inside with onClick property pass a callback function that should be called next. For what I've read this approach is not the proper redux way due to the fact that callbacks are not serializable and I should not keep them in store. I've tried it anyway :D It works(but I won't be sticking to this solution), but the problem is that I am trying to reference properties of the redux state in those callbacks and those doesn't seem to update since the moment the entry object has been dispatched.

That is the approach that I did for now in my custom react hook that handles the logic for different steps(it's wrong).

```js
dispatch(
    addHistoryEntry({
        title: 'Some redirect response',
        type: 'response - redirect',
        responseObject: {
            status: 302,
            statusText: 'Found',
        },
        /* some other stuff */
        callToActionButton: {
            innerText: 'Follow',
            iconText: 'key',
            onClick: doSomethingCallback,
        },
    })
);

// ...

function doSomethingCallback() {
    console.log(somethingFromReduxStore);
}
```

and in react ui component

```
{
    entry.callToActionButton && (
            <Button
                variant="dark"
                onClick={entry.callToActionButton.onClick}
            >
                {entry.callToActionButton.iconText && (
                    <span className="material-symbols-outlined me-2">
                        {entry.callToActionButton.iconText}
                    </span>
                )}
                {entry.callToActionButton.innerText}
            </Button>
    );
}
```

My question is - **how to reference callback functions properly from redux state**?